# How to save Files in Android/Media/MyFolder in Android11 and above

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

Hy everyone, I am new to SAF and know how to get uri from Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.I have checked my logcat and receive the URI as content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses. Suppose I want to make a folder and save downloaded files. How can I achieve this? How can I tell DownloadManager to download to this URI. Is there any other way to achieve the same then Please tell me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the normal way as usual.

Instantiate a DocumentFile instance for the obtained uri and then use createFile on it to make your subfolder.

There is no possibility to let DownloadManager download to that folder.